# Laravel application works on local Homestead but not on Heroku - Sentinel error

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5, homestead

**Laravel 5.5 

Latest Sentinel (for authentication) 

Homestead virtual machine (on my local machine)**

Basically, I have an app that works perfectly on local Homestead machine.
I have created a new app on Heroku, everything works fine except login and register. I have ClearDB database setup, migrations work perfectly, so database connection is good.

But when I try to login or register, I get an error. For whatever reason, a `username` is not passed to the database. Every other value is passed. (I changed `EloquentUser`, so I can login with `Username`)

I use `Sentinel::registerAndActivate($request->all());` code for registration. All names from form are matching to names in db. Like I said, it works on local machine.

When I `dd($request->all()`, I can see username is passed.

I have added username in `$fillable` array and in `EloquentUser` for Sentinel.

Any ideas why is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupid thing to be honest. You have to create your own model that extends original Sentinel user model because when you are changing login method you have to edit a file which is in `vendor` folder, which is overwritten every time you deploy something on Heroku.

Just create your model file in `App` folder and extend EloquentUser model from vendor folder. Add `$fillable` and `$protected` arrays. Change `cartalyst.sentinel.php` file in settings, so `'model'` is now your own, not `EloquentUser`.